# Keyframe wont work in Chrome, webkit?

Tags: css, webkit

I've tried to find a solution for a long time now, but i cant get it to work in Chrome. Can someone show how to use the -webkit command? This is the css code that works in IE:

```
    @keyframes swingdown {
    0% {
        opacity: .99999;
        transform: rotateX(90deg);

    }

    30% {           
        transform: rotateX(-20deg) rotateY(5deg);
        animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
    }

    65% {
        transform: rotateX(20deg) rotateY(-3deg);
        animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
    }

    100% {
        transform: rotateX(0);
        animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
    }
}
```

The html is a simple menu:

```
<body>
 <div id="container">
<ul id="menu">
  <li><a href="#">About Me</a>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#"></a></li>
        <li><a href="#"></a></li>
        <li><a href="#"></a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
<li><a href="#">Portfolio</a>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#"></a></li>
        <li><a href="#"></a></li>
        <li><a href="#"></a></li>
        <li><a href="#"></a></li>
        <li><a href="#"></a></li>
        <li><a href="#"></a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
<li><a href="#">Clients</a>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#"></a></li>
        <li><a href="#"></a></li>
        <li><a href="#"></a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
<li><a href="#">Contact Me</a>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#"></a></li>
        <li><a href="#"></a></li>
        <li><a href="#"></a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
<li><a href="#">Support</a></li>
 </ul>
 </div>
 </body>
```

Comment: http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-animation

Answer (score 0):

use this

```
@-webkit-keyframes swingdown {
0% {
    opacity: .99999;
    -webkit-transform: rotateX(90deg);

}

30% {           
    -webkit-transform: rotateX(-20deg) rotateY(5deg);
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
}

65% {
    -webkit-transform: rotateX(20deg) rotateY(-3deg);
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
}

100% {
    -webkit-transform: rotateX(0);
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
}
}
```

basically use -webkit- before all animation part

Comment: See above! Notice that it works in IE, the -webkit- does not work for some reason.

Comment: are u using all animations properties? such as duration, name iteration count etc.

Comment: I dont know lol, im pretty new to the animation part, i got this from a friend who sent it to me, trying to understand it! The keyframe above is everything i got

Comment: because of that comment, you are getting a -1 for the question

Comment: I didnt mean that this was the first time i ever worked with animation on a site, but i dont quite understand the -webkit command and asked for help, i dont think that was whort a -1. It was my first post.